# Handout framed, but end if slides end

Tags: beamer, handout

I have a presentation and I would like to offer a handout version, I got this code.
But the problem is, it does automatically 4 frames on each page. Even if the Last page has just one slide, 4 frames are made and consequentially 3 are empty. How can I handle this "bug"?

```
% for Handout use: 
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,landscape,border shrink=5mm]
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Different approach: add a border to the background of every frame in handout mode:

```
\documentclass[
  handout
]{beamer}


\mode<handout>{
  \usepackage{pgfpages}
  \pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,landscape,border shrink=5mm]
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
      \draw (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 


\end{document}
```

[image]